# Linking three tables SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables towns , patientsHome,patientsRecords

**towns**

> Id
>   1
>   2
>   3

**patientsHome**

> Id     |     serial_number
>   1       |       11 
>   2       |       12
>   2       |       13

**patientsRecords**

> status  |     serial_number
>   stable  |       11 
>   expire  |       12 
>   expire  |       13

I want to count stable and expire patients from patients records against each  Id from towns.

output should be like

**Result**

> Id| stableRecords |expiredRecords  
>   1|    1  |     0   
>   2|    0  |     2  
>   3|    0  |     0

Comment: and please also attach (the code) what you've tried so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
select t.id,case when tt.StableRecords is null then 0 else tt.StableRecords end
as StableRecords,case when tt.expiredRecords is null then 0 else tt.expiredRecords
end as expiredRecords from towns t left join
(select ph.id, count(case when pr.status='stable' then 1 end) as StableRecords,
count(Case when pr.status='expire' then 1 end) as expiredRecords
from patientsRecords pr inner join 
patientsHome ph on ph.serial_number=pr.serial_number
group by ph.id ) as tt 
on t.id=tt.id
```

Comment: sir, how can i fill the empty fields to 0 they are giving empty i m using postgresql

Comment: @user3301246 now check answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `patientsHome.ID` is in fact a foreign key to `towns.ID`, you can join the 3 tables, filter as appropriate, group by Town, and count the rows:

```
SELECT t.Id, COUNT(*) as patientCount
FROM towns t
  INNER JOIN patientsHome ph
    on t.Id = ph.Id
  INNER JOIN patientsRecords pr
    on ph.serialNumber = pr.serialNumber
WHERE pr.status in ('stable', 'expire')
GROUP BY t.Id;
```

If you also want to classify the status per town:

```
SELECT t.Id, pr.status, COUNT(*) as patientCount
... FROM, WHERE same as above
GROUP BY t.Id, pr.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, pr.status,
  COUNT(*) AS countByStatus
FROM patientsRecords pr
INNER JOIN patientsHome ph
ON ph.serial_number = pr.serial_number
INNER JOIN towns t
ON t.id=ph.id
WHERE pr.status  IN ('stable', 'expire')
GROUP BY t.id, pr.status;
```

See the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/028545/4

Comment: I think i did't explain myself correctly, I want to get stable records count in stable column and expired records in expired column against each town id.

Comment: Mmm, what is the problem?